# How to update variable inside promise then & catch

Tags: javascript

I am using sequalize & trying to build a small function to check DB connection status

```
const DBStatus = async(data)=>{
    sequelize
      .authenticate()
      .then(() => {
        data.status=true;
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
      })
      .catch(err => {
    data.status=false;
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
      });
    return data
}
```

I want to return data.status based on promise status

Comment: you need to `await`.

Comment: I am using await while calling this function or am I missing something

Comment: you can await in here.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `async` you should use the `await` keyword with `try / catch`, not `.then` and `catch`

```
const DBStatus = async (data) => {
    try {
        const result = await sequelize.authenticate();
        data.status = true;
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        // if you want to resolve this promise with a value then use return
        return result
    } catch(err) {
        data.status=false;
        // if you want to reject the promise with a value then use throw
        throw err;
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see it working console.log(result ) returns undefined.                                          
 I did                                                                                                                       
   await sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  }) and was able to see console statement

Comment: I'm glad that you have working code but that syntax doesn't make sense